# PHP Mailer classe não funciona

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estou tentando enviar um email pelo php usando o *PHP MAILER* porém sempre recebo o erro de classe inexistente e já não sei o que fazer.

Erro:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /home/ortop753/public_html/teste.php on line 6
```

Código:

```
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use php\composers\PHPMailer;
use php\composers\Exception;

require 'php/composers/Exception.php';
require 'php/composers/PHPMailer.php';
require 'php/composers/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
   //.... //
```

SRC PHPMailer:

```
class PHPMailer
 { 
    // A Classe esta correta
```

Comment: O caminho dos requires está correto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A informação do erro é que ele não está achando arquivo no caminho que você está passando, o arquivo de onde você está fazendo a chamada pode estar em uma hierarquia diferente do que você imagina, então recomendo utilizar a função do php `file_exists()` para fazer essa checagem, faça alguns testes e até achar o real caminho do arquivo e ajuste sua aplicação.

um exemplo da função `file_exists()`

```
if(!require 'php/composers/PHPMailer.php'){
   require '../php/composers/PHPMailer.php';
}
```

Nesse exemplo você verifica se existe o arquivo, caso não exista sobe um nível, existem casos que dependendo de onde você fizer a chamada a hierarquia pode estar certa, e outros casos você tenha que ir para outra pasta, dessa maneira resolveria o problema.

Segue referência da função do PHP: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-exists.php